# minima of smooth curve

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to find the minimal point of a smooth curve made with tikz, so i can mark it with a spot, however the smooth curve slightly moves minima and maxima. I could offcourse just move the spots, but wondered if there was a smart way to do it.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
%Opsætning af koordinater
\coordinate (bottom) at (5,1);
\coordinate (lmen) at (3 , 2.75);
\coordinate (lman) at (4.5 , 3.25);
\coordinate (rmen) at (6.7,3.35);
\coordinate (rman) at (6.15,4.75);
\coordinate (lkant) at (0,4.756);
\coordinate (rkant) at (7,4.55);
\coordinate (o) at (0,0);
\coordinate (x) at (7,0);
\coordinate (y) at (0,5);

%tegn grafsystem
\draw [<->] (y) -- node [rotate=90, above] {Energy of konfiguration} (o) -> node [below] {Place in konfiguration space} (x);
\node [rotate = 90] at (-0.1,2.5) {Energy of konfiguration};

% Selve energikurven
\draw [green!80] plot [smooth] coordinates {(lkant) (lmen) (lman) (bottom) (rman) (rmen) (rkant)};

%lagels og sådant

\filldraw[color = blue!50] (bottom) circle  (0.1) node [below,color=black] {\tiny Global minima};
\filldraw [color = red!50] (lmen) circle (0.1) node [below,color=black] {\tiny Local minima trap};
\filldraw [color = red!50] (rmen) circle (0.1) node [below,color=black] {\tiny Local minima trap};
\filldraw [color = yellow!50] (lman) circle (0.1) node [above,color=black] {\tiny Local maxima};
\filldraw [color = yellow!50] (rman) circle (0.1) node [above,color=black] {\tiny Local maxima};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Produced picture

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example specifies the input and output angles of the curve to ensure that the points are minima and maxima:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%Opsætning af koordinater
\coordinate (bottom) at (5,1);
\coordinate (lmen) at (3 , 2.75);
\coordinate (lman) at (4.5 , 3.25);
\coordinate (rmen) at (6.7,3.35);
\coordinate (rman) at (6.15,4.75);
\coordinate (lkant) at (0,4.756);
\coordinate (rkant) at (7,4.55);
\coordinate (o) at (0,0);
\coordinate (x) at (7,0);
\coordinate (y) at (0,5);

%tegn grafsystem
\draw [<->] (y) -- node [rotate=90, above] {Energy of konfiguration} (o) -> node [below] {Place in konfiguration space} (x);

% Selve energikurven
% \draw [green!80] plot [smooth, tension=.2] coordinates {(lkant) (lmen) (lman) (bottom) (rman) (rmen) (rkant)};
\draw [green!80, in=180, out=0, tension=.1]
  (lkant)[out=-10] to (lmen) to (lman) to (bottom) to (rman) to (rmen) to (rkant);

%lagels og sådant

\filldraw[color = blue!50] (bottom) circle  (0.1) node [below,color=black] {\tiny Global minima};
\filldraw [color = red!50] (lmen) circle (0.1) node [below,color=black] {\tiny Local minima trap};
\filldraw [color = red!50] (rmen) circle (0.1) node [below,color=black] {\tiny Local minima trap};
\filldraw [color = yellow!50] (lman) circle (0.1) node [above,color=black] {\tiny Local maxima};
\filldraw [color = yellow!50] (rman) circle (0.1) node [above,color=black] {\tiny Local maxima};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The horizontal distance between a yellow marked local maximum and the following minimum is too small to get a nice smooth curve without bending backwards.

For example:

```
\coordinate (lkant) at (0,4.756);
\coordinate (lmen) at (1.8, 2.75);
\coordinate (lman) at (3.1, 3.25);
\coordinate (bottom) at (4.1, 1);
\coordinate (rman) at (5.6, 4.75);
\coordinate (rmen) at (6.4, 3.35);
\coordinate (rkant) at (7, 4.55);
...
\draw [green!80, in=180, out=0, tension=.1]
  (lkant)[out=-10] to (lmen) to (lman) to (bottom) to (rman) to (rmen)
  to [in=245](rkant);
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Would like to get the sharper curves by the \draw [color] plot [smooth] coordinates {(a,b) (c,d) (e,f)}; syntax, but this works great ,thanks XD